# Issue using Trait in markdown mail template

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I'm trying to use php Trait method inside my markdown mail template in laravel, problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
 ErrorException  : Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::getExcerpt() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dtcburger.com\resources\views\emails\weekly\weekly-mail-1.blade.php)
```

I'm trying to use getExcerpt mehod from my Strings php Trait class, but it's not working.

This is my  mailable class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail\weekly;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Traits\Strings;


class WeeklyMail1 extends Mailable
{


    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    use Strings;
    public $mailData;


    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        $mail = $this->markdown('emails.weekly.weekly-mail-1')
        ->from(env('MAIL_FROM'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
        ->subject($this->mailData['subject']);

        return $mail;
    }


}
```

And my markdown mail template:

```
@component('mail::message', ['mailData' => $mailData])

# {{ $mailData['subject'] }}

@if(count($mailData['events']) > 0)
# No te pierdas nuestros próximos eventos
@component('mail::table')
|  |  |
| :------------- | :------------- |
@foreach($mailData['events'] as $event)
| <img src="{{ $event->image }}" style="min-width:120px; max-width:120px; min-height:100px; max-height:100px;"> | <strong><p>{{ $event->title }}</p></strong><p>{{!! $this->getExcerpt($event->body, 0, 100) !!}}</p> |
@endforeach
@endcomponent
@endif

@endcomponent
```

And my Strings Trait with method getExcerpt inside:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Str;

trait Strings
{
    public function slugify($title){
        $cleanString = $this->cleanString($title);
        $slugified = Str::lower( Str::slug($title, '-') );
        return $slugified;
    }


    public function getExcerpt($str, $startPos = 0, $maxLength = 30, $end = '[...]') {
        if(strlen($str) > $maxLength) {
            $excerpt   = substr($str, $startPos, $maxLength - 6);
            $lastSpace = strrpos($excerpt, ' ');
            $excerpt   = substr($excerpt, 0, $lastSpace);
            $excerpt  .= $end;
        } else {
            $excerpt = $str;
        }

        return $excerpt;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your are no more in your WeeklyMail class context.

I suggest you just do an accessor to your event Model wich does

```
use Strings;

function getExcerptBodyAttribute(){
      return $this->getExcerpt($this->body, 0, 100)
}
```

And then in your template

```
<img src="{{ $event->image }}" style="min-width:120px; max-width:120px; min-height:100px; max-height:100px;"> | <strong><p>{{ $event->title }}</p></strong><p>{{!! $event->excerpt_body !!}}</p>
```

if your event is not an eloquent model, juste make a setter which set his `excerpt_body`